# Regex mid-string pattern exclustion

Tags: regex, url

I need help with a regular expression for use with UrlRewriting.Net.  I have two URLs -

`http://domain/SomeFolder/tracks/SomeFileName/`

and

`http://domain/SomeFolder/<could be anything>/SomeFileName/`

For URL rewriting purposes I need to come up with one expression that will let me target specifically the URL with "tracks" in the middle of it.  I need another expression to catch everything without "tracks" in it.

Before I had this constraint I was using `^~/SomeFolder/([^/]*)/SomeFileName/?$` and that worked as my catch-all.  Now that I have this specific "tracks" folder, I can't use the catch all.

Make sense?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you just order the expressions so that if it matches the "tracks" one, it ignores the catch-all?

Comment: Tried that.  Because the number of path segments are the same, reordering them causes the second expression to supersede the first expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^~/SomeFolder/(?!tracks/)([^/]*)/SomeFileName/?$
```

and

```
^~/SomeFolder/(tracks)/SomeFileName/?$
```